# How to avoid unnecessary namespace declarations in a marshalled element/tag?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

I have a XSD which is not self created but received from another party. So I can't change this XSD because I must ensure comptibility with the other party.

Using XJC 2.2 and JAXB 2.2 using simple binding mode I want to create an root element with inside an empty hello element. But when marshalled I get a lot of extra namespace crap. Which to me looks unneeded. (It works though, but it's more data to send ect...)

XSD Rootelement:

```
<element name="epp">
        <complexType>
            <choice>
                <element name="greeting" type="epp:greetingType" />
                <element name="hello" />
                <element name="command" type="epp:commandType" />
                <element name="response" type="epp:responseType" />
                <element name="extension" type="epp:extAnyType" />
            </choice>
        </complexType>
    </element>
```

Java code:

```
Epp epp = new Epp(); 
epp.setHello("");
```

Marshalled Result:

```
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
     <hello xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string"></hello>
</epp>
```

Preferred Result:

```
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
<hello />
</epp>
```

Or:

```
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
<hello></hello>
</epp>
```

Is there any way to make this possible, preferably without changing XSD or manually change the  XJC compiled classes?

Comment: Mind if I edit the question title? It feels like you're asking how to generate an element without content, but that's taken care of. The real goal is avoiding superfluous namespace declarations.

Comment: No problem, it's my first question on here... :), Yes the goal is to get rid of those namespace decs

Comment: Did you try not setting Hello value (not running epp.setHello(""))?

Comment: Yes, but that creates just an empty root element. Since the hello element is not required. There should be at least one of these elements in the root element.

I have tried setting the hello as required, but it will be always present even if there is a command element. Thus resulting is an invalid xsd validation from the other party.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is as follows: the schema doesn't define a type for element `hello`. As a result, XJC generates a field with type `Object`. That means that JAXB must detect, during marshalling, what kind of object we're dealing with. I'm not certain about the details, but I suppose it'll check the runtime type and then deals with it accordingly. Since `String` - which is what you actually put into the `hello` field - has a direct binding to a schema type (namely `xs:string`) JAXB is gonna go with that. So far, so good.

But JAXB is trying to generate XML that'll be useful for unmarshalling as well. Since the schema didn't specify a type and the `hello` field is an Object, trying to unmarshal from XML would leave JAXB guessing as to what it should actually turn the content into. One way to tell it how is to specify the type in the XML element, using the `xsi:type` attribute. This attribute falls within the `xsi`-bound namespace, so that prefix must be declared and bound. That's what happens with `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`. But that's not all... The declared `xsi:type` makes use of a type in the XML Schema namespace, bound to prefix `xs` which means THAT must be declared as well! Hence the `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`.

The result: a mess of namespace declarations just to tell whoever uses the XML that it does, in fact, contain a string. This could be solved by adding string as the type for the hello element in the schema, but that's not an option for you.

Fortunately, you're not totally out of luck. You can customize bindings using an external bindings file. Details can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html

Normally, this bindings file ought to do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <!-- Bindings for the general schema -->
    <bindings schemaLocation="test.xsd" node="/xs:schema">

        <bindings node="xs:element[@name='epp']">
            <bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='hello']">
                <javaType name="java.lang.String" />
            </bindings>
        </bindings>

    </bindings>

</bindings>
```

... but when I try xjc with this I'm getting the error `the compiler was unable to honor this javaType customization`. It does work when I specify some standard schema type (like string or int) on the hello element in the schema, but again didn't work when I actually tried to supply parse and print methods for the conversion, so I'm gonna have to assume this is a bug in xjc that occurs when no type is specified in the schema.

I'm hoping someone else can give advice regarding the bindings issue. Otherwise, the only option I see is sending your schema through some XSLT transform prior to unleashing XJC on it to set every non-typed element to string by default.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately I get the same errors...

While I'm using `epp.setHello("");` to let the marshaller know it should output the element. Maybe there is another way of setting the hello element that doesn't generate a string. 

Since XJC compiles the function as a `public void setHello(Object value)` using null is just like not setting it and will not be picked up by the marshaller. To make a "stupid" guess, is there a JAXB "null" Object? :)

Comment: @PhoenixtheII Did you use the bindings file? If so, did it work? I've been using he XJC distributed with JDK 7, so maybe previous versions work with this. I know you want to "force in" the hello element by setting an empty String for it, and that **is** the right approach. Setting null would result in it being omitted. But our goal here is to turn the hello field in the `Epp` class into some concrete type, since it being an `Object` is what's causing all the xsi:type fluff to be added in.

Comment: Ah well, I've decided to do the "screw it" mode since I initially already made changes to the parties xsd to make something JAXB compatible (@XmlRootElement missing stuff ;)). And did as you told: I've changed the xsd to tell that the hello element is of a string type. `<element name="hello" type="string"/>` and still using the same Java code gives me my preferred result. Now I hope that my XSD is still compatible with receiving these hello's but I'll have to test that...

Comment: @GH's Comment: I'm using the downloaded JAXB implementation 2.2.4u1. Not the bundled JDK6 outdated stuff (which was 2.1.10), the command I use to compile this: `../../../../../../lib/jaxb-2.2.4u1/jaxb-ri-20110601/bin/xjc.sh epp-1.0.xsd -episode epp-1.0.episode -b eppcom-1.0.episode -extension ../xjcExtensions.xml -catalog epp.cat -p com.somelocation.x.y.z.epp1 -d ../../../../../` Where xjcExtensions.xml has the added binding info you described + a "globalBindings <xjc: simple /> "

Comment: I'd be surprised if declaring something as a string would lead to problems. I thought it was the default anyway, but have a hard time finding confirmation or what really *is* the default type of an element according to XML Schema. Anyways, if manually altering the schema is workable for you (not like, say, 100s of these element declarations with daily builds), it'll do the trick. And even without that, at least the XML is well-formed and valid. Some extra bytes won't hurt, ugly though it may be. Got redundant namespace issues mmyself "thanks" to @XmlSeeAlso.

Comment: I'd be suprised aswell, but still... :)

I'd rather save a diff between original and modified xsd. So that in the future I might apply the same changes again. Than modifying autogenerated stuff... And parsing the marshalled xml trough a "prettifier" is plain stupid performance wise...

Comment: Well... JAXB has a JAXBSource and JAXBResult class that can be used to transform from/to beans. You can transform straight from a bean to XML with an XSLT transform in the middle. Should be rather performant, and maybe it can help somehow. But then again, last time I tried using XSLT to clean unused namespaces I ended up making it worse ;°_°

Answer (score 1):

When the schema doesn't specify a type for an element, the default type is `xs:anyType`, which is the root of the XML Schema type hierarchy (all simple and complex types are subtypes of `anyType`).

When JAXB encounters an `anyType` element it will bind it to a property of type `Object`. The value you put into this property can be

- `null`, meaning omit the element
- an object of a type the JAXBContext knows about, which will be marshalled in the normal way and an `xsi:type` added to indicate what the original type was, or
- an `org.w3c.dom.Element` representing the actual XML to use.

So try this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

epp.setHello(doc.createElementNS("urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0", "hello"));
```